# Weird Network Requirement

Tags: windows, networking

I have a question that is pretty dumb but I can't figure it out and I have spent more time on it than I want to.

I have a network that has 3 computers on it.

Computer A is the main computer it needs access to the internet and Computer B,

Computer B is a backup server

Computer C Can not be connected to the internet but needs to be connect to Computer B.

Currently there is no backup solution and files are transferred between A and C by USB Drive.

I was planning on two networks,

Net1 will be connected to the router and A and B.

Net2 will be connected to B and C.

Any solutions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is more a question for superuser ;) http://superuser.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not related to programming

Answer (score 0):

Add an additional network card to Computer B and use it to connect with computer C